# Endogeneity: Different composite variables as dep. and indep. variables in regression equation but both have a common variable

Tags: regression, endogeneity, cross-section

I am working on firm-level survey data. It is a cross-section.

Method of obtaining dependent variable of regression equation:
1. log(gross value added)-log(fixed assets)-log(employment)
2. taking median value as -1 and scaling all other values accordingly

One of my independent variables: Fuel exp. / gross value added

So, in short, there is a common variable (gross value added) on my LHS and RHS. I have checked the correlation between these, which is low, but doesn't this model entail endogeneity?